# How to make a spinning text button

Tags: jquery, css, uibutton

To day I have a very easy question (But I used whole day to find the tutorials)I want to make button like this site:
http://www.koogco.no/
Look at the social buttons on the right, whn mouse rollover the button is spinning.

I have tried many keyword like : spinning button jquery, animate button etc. But I can´t find the name or even tutorials.

Can somebody help me to point this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is a CSS solution.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
.container {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img-container {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.21,1.22,1,1.31);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img-top {
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff&text=2);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.img-bottom {
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff&text=1);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.img-container:hover {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"></div>
    <div class="img-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Replicating the one on [this site](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html) as you requested.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: brown;
}
.home {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: brown;
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0D0605;
  opacity: 0.9;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #0D0605;
  opacity: 0.9
}
.img-container {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.21, 1.22, 1, 1.31);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.img-top {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  width: 70p;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-container:hover {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">HOME</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">ABOUT</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="">SERVICE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">SERVICE</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">CONTACT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah seem like this one is cool. But What if I want to have more than one button ? And want it work like this :
templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html

Comment: My I ask you last question ?
Refer to this link : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html
I´m trying to add sub menu when rollover the "SERVICE".But what can I do ? I´m all blind with this. So difficult. This is very advance methode for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 transitions. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ and, for example, http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/. Specifically,

1. Use absolute positioning for the button image and e.g. relative for its container.
2. Position the inactive state image the way you want and the active state image e.g. above it.
3. For the active state, move the active state image in the place of the inactive state image and the latter below the former.
4. When it looks the way you want, add a transition property. It should look like `transition: top 1s ease-in-out;`.

Comment: Hi thank you. Do you know the exact tutorials of the button that I want ? The problem is I dont know the name of this effect.

Comment: No. However, it shouldn't be too difficult; just move the inactive state image to some direction and the active image in its place by using the position attribute and apply a transitions.

Comment: To be more closer, I actually want to do like this site : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html

I don´t know if they use image for this. But anyway I´m not so good in Css3.

Answer (score 0):

create a background with both images, one on top of the other.
set

```
background-position: 0px 20px;
```

then animate background position with

```
transition : all .2s;
```

by setting the :hover style to

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the websites from where you could download many animated social media icons that uses "hover Effect":

1. http://designscrazed.org/html-css3-social-media-buttons/
2. http://techfameplus.com/social-media-icons-with-hover-effect/